# Edit Bootstrap's span width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to Twitter's bootstrap and i have a question that i cant figure out.
This is the code that i want to adjust.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {.span2 {width: 180px;}
```

When my site is "full" the width has to be 220px when i adjust the css this will work fine. When i resize my window to a smaller resolution the images are not scaling to the correct size in this case 160px. How can i do this?

Has this something to do with:

```
.row-fluid .span2 {
   width: 14.364640883%;
   *width: 14.311449393638298%;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some more information (code?) ? You speak of "images" while you show `span`-css. Using Twitter Bootstrap defines something like a layout-grid. Scaling down your browser-window is equal to looking at your page with a smaller device (mobiles, iPads...). Resizing elements and setting them to `display: block;` is intended! open this page http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem and resize your browser to see what happens!

Answer (score -2):

You use !important in style bootstraps

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {.span2 {width: 180px !important;}
.row-fluid .span2 {
width: 14.364640883% !important;
*width: 14.311449393638298% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! The adjustment to 220px works at min-width: 1200px but when i am resizing my browser to one size smaller the span is going to width: 140px this is not defined in the css but calculated?

Comment: sorry, no! don´t use `!important` here!